# IBM integration toolkit: oracle packages shown empty in database explorer

Tags: eclipse, oracle, ibm-integration-bus

At first I created **Driver Definition** in properties
[image: new driver definition]

Then I created new Data **Design Project** and **Database definition file**
[image: database definition file]

After creating connection to db I selected database elements for the model.
[image: database elements for the model]

Although I selected routines, It is not shown routines under packages in **Database Explorer**. All packages are shown empty.
[image: Database Explorer]

In DB there are functions under marked packages. How to access them. the user which I connected by, have access to these functions.

Comment: *"packages are shown empty."* Do you mean you can't see the signature of the  functions (i.e. the contents of the package **spec**) or you can't see the internal routines of the functions (i.e. the contents of the package **body**)???

Comment: I don’t know IBM Integration Toolkit, but are the packages *not shown* or are they *shown empty*? Are you connecting as the package owner? It is normal for packages to contain private subprograms that are not visible to other users. (@APC beat me to it...)

Comment: I cannot see the functions and procedures under package. I found that information about packages are retrieved. They exists in .dbm file as xml tag. But they not shown in the database explorer and database routine selection wizard

Comment: This seems like a bug in the tool. You should take this up with IBM Support